# Run multiple timers in the same page using javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]The below code prints the title of many cards and their countdown time.....the problem is that the timer is printed only for the first card. How do i print it for all the cards?I've tried a lot to search it on google but could find a relevant answer.Please help me on how to get timers on each card.

```
function previewall()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {
},
url: "readall.php",
dataType: "json",
 success: function(JSONObject) {
  var peopleHTML = "";
  for (var key in JSONObject) {
    if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {       
        peopleHTML += "<div class='wrapper'><label>" + JSONObject[key]["title"] + "</label><br>";
        peopleHTML += "<p id='demo1'></p><br><p id=demo></p> </div>";
 var x = setInterval(function() {
      var count =JSONObject[key]["valid_date"];
    var dat=JSONObject[key]["started_date"];
    var countDownDate = new Date(count).getTime();
    var date = new Date(dat).getTime();

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();
var elapsed = now - date;
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var planned= date - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

var days1 = Math.floor(elapsed / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours1 = Math.floor((elapsed % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes1 = Math.floor((elapsed % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds1 = Math.floor((elapsed % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

var days2 = Math.floor(planned / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours2 = Math.floor((planned % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes2 = Math.floor((planned % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds2 = Math.floor((planned % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);    

if (distance < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
else if(elapsed<0){     
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Starts in " + days2 + "d " + hours2 + "h " + minutes2 + "m " + seconds2 + "s " ;  
}
else
{
     document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Posted <br>" + days1 + "d " + hours1 + "h " + minutes1 + "m " + seconds1 + "s ago" ;

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s Left" ;
}
    });
    }
  }
 $("#people").html(peopleHTML);
 }
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all timers bind the variable `key`, so when they fire, they see the final value of `key`.

Try this instead:

```
for (var k in JSONObject) {
   let key = k;
   if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     ...
```

Comment: Not sure how your HTML page looks like, but shouldn't you create one distinct HTML element for each card that is to be updated? Currently, everything is written to the same `demo` resp. `demo1` elements.

Comment: mine is a dynamic page.The number of cards changes frequently.so i cant create the elements right.

Comment: ive added the image of the sample output.Have a look at it @ammoQ

Comment: The ids in each card must be distinct, see Alex' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements sharing the same `id` (i.e. demo, demo1), the resulting page is broken and this is the cause of the issue.

The fastest fix would be keeping a counter and embedding it in the various `id`s of the elements you create dinamically.

Something like:

```
var peopleHTML = "";
var i = -1;
for (var key in JSONObject) {
i++;
if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {       
    peopleHTML += "<div class='wrapper'><label>" + JSONObject[key]["title"] + "</label><br>";
    peopleHTML += "<p id='demoOuter'"+i+"></p><br><p id=demoInner"+i+"></p> </div>";

// [CUT]

f (distance < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demoInner"+i).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
else if(elapsed<0){     
        document.getElementById("demoOuter"+i).innerHTML = "Starts in " + days2 + "d " + hours2 + "h " + minutes2 + "m " + seconds2 + "s " ;  
}
else
{
     document.getElementById("demoOuter"+i).innerHTML = "Posted <br>" + days1 + "d " + hours1 + "h " + minutes1 + "m " + seconds1 + "s ago" ;

     document.getElementById("demoInner"+i).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s Left" ;
}
```

Comment: Formatting is a bit lousy but the approach should be evident

Comment: When i run the code, it showed time only for the last card this time.I guess i am very much close to the answer now. @Alex